# Can I use a variable in one file, and then require it in another?

Tags: php, html, templates, web, require

I have two files, one for php and the other one is a template contaning html. I am using a Load template function to make it neat and easily reusable.

```
//HTML
             <table>
             <thead>
             <tr>
             <td>Name</td>
             <td>Comment</td>
             <td></td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                     <tr>
 **<h2><?php echo $category['admin']; ?></h2>
    <td><a style="float: right" href="editadmin.php?id=' . $category['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';**
                     <td><form method="post" action="deleteadmin.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $category['id'] . '" />
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
                        </form></td>
                     </tr>
            </table>
```

```
//PHP
require '../../loadTemplate.php';
$output = loadTemplate('../../templates/admintable.html.php', []);
require  '../../templates/layout.html.php';

$categories = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM admin'); 

foreach ($categories as $category) {
```

```
//Load template
function loadTemplate($fileName, $templateVars) {
       extract($templateVars);
        ob_start();
        require $fileName;
        $contents = ob_get_clean();
        return $contents;
```

I want to require that HTML file inside the PHP file and create a table for editing and deleting some data, but when I use a variable in the HTML.PHP file and require it inside PHP one, it tells me that the Variable is Undefined (the $category). I'm fairly new to it and still learning and I just cant get my head around it, is there a way to use a variable in html.php and require it in PHP where its declared ?

Comment: um build your data, then call `$output = loadTemplate(.. ['category' => [..result from foreach])` dont think, import or sniff at rendering the template before you have the data.

Comment: I did as you said and it still shows an error

Comment: You should use your loadTemplate function for **all** templates, one feeds into the other etc. Its unclear what the two require's you have output. Use a framework if your starting out, fatfree is lightweight and easy to understand, also routing and mvc can be done in just a few lines: https://gist.github.com/lcherone/74c17dcee670392ff047b008b91cc355 and building up from that, https://github.com/lcherone/PlinkerUI/tree/master/public maybe its of some intrest. basically you need to load data first, then pass to your partials then the result of the rendered partial goes in the main template